# What are other middleware alternatives for PgBouncer and PgPool II?

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, benchmarking, pgpool, pgbouncer

I am trying to find what are the different middleware available to work with Postgres DB. Every one is recommending about PgBouncer and PgPool II. What are the list of other middleware that I can work with.

Comment: What's wrong with pgPool and pgBouncer?

Comment: Just want to know what other middlewares existing

Comment: PgPool has a lot of issues, from my experience, esp bugs in failover scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

Example list of other middlewares:

1. https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP
2. https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0
3. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html
4. https://github.com/yandex/odyssey

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I am new to the connection pooling concept and references you have given, gave me a overview and helped me to search more. Now my question is, do we have any middleware that we can configure at database server side without any configuration changes required in application ? Let me know if you did not get my point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: PgBouncer works by mimicking itself as a Postgres server - so your application does not need any changes when you start using PgBouncer (of course you will have to update the connection string)

Comment: Understood, I am trying to gather the benchmark results for PgBouncer like middleware. All I am able to see is PgBouncer and PgPool II. Here my question is what are the others that I can compare.

Comment: Keep in mind that PgBouncer is single-threaded so you may need to run several instances of it if you need more throughput. Also look for balance - pgBouncer will not help you if the database itself is loaded with slow queries, the clients will simply wait in the queue.